# Как передать data атрибуты с одной страницы на другую?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Суть сделать скачивание файлов на отдельной странице.

Это ссылка на отдельную страницу для скачивания файла, открывается в новом окне

```
<a href="download.html" target="_blank"
data-downtitle="название" data-downreads="трек.mp3">
перейти к скачиванию
</a>
```

Как в `download.html или .php` вывести эти дата атрибуты?

```
<a href="трек.mp3" title="название">скачать</a>
```

Или может другое решение есть?

Comment: если это должна быть обычная ссылка - то только в параметры url перенести

Comment: Каким образом в url ?

Comment: `href="download.html?downreads=трек.mp3&downtitle=название` примерно так, и не использовать дата атрибуты

Comment: Нужно перенести это `трек.mp3` в `download.html` , а там ссылкой скачать.

Comment: А в `download.html` как вывести?

Comment: а что это за страница-то? например берете и, так как у вас php, получаете из url параметров. например `$_GET["downreads"]` и потом просто используете эти значения для генерации ссылки

Comment: А какая ссылка на скачивание ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32559/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно просто через get параметр передать.

Будет как то так:

```
Download.php?title=название&reads=трек.mp3
```

А скрипт принимает параметры и отдает на скачивание нужный файл

Comment: Какой скрипт то? Нужно чтоб в `Download.php` была ссылка на файл. А путь к файлу передаётся с первой страницы data-downreads="трек.mp3"

Comment: ну вот вы get параметром передаете путь до файла $_GET['reads']
на php пишете скрипт который отдаем уже этот файл как вам нужно и когда вам нужно.

Comment: И как в php сделать такую ссылку <a href="трек.mp3">скачать</a>

Comment: @СергейЛапшин, вы же сказали в чате, что вам ясно

Comment: Я же не спрашивал, где мне мануал по php почитать?

Comment: Или так:
`<a href="<?=$_GET['reads']?>">скачать</a>`
Но не все браузеры скачают тогда. Они могут просто открыть mp3 и проиграть его.
Чтоб точно скачалось можно сделать так
`<a href="<?=$_GET['reads']?>" download>скачать</a>`

Comment: @СергейЛапшин, а вы хотели чтобы за вас просто все решили?

Comment: А с `download.html` можно как нибудь? С php не получается.

Comment: нет. html - это язык разметки а не язык программирования. Логика пишется на языках программирования.

Comment: С php не получается. Как в php эту ссылку вписать?

Comment: выше написал: `<a href="<?=$_GET['reads']?>" download>скачать</a>`

Comment: Извиняюсь, букву пропустил.